# How to increase performance when creating lots relations in neo4j

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I am working on a crawler to analyze the internal link structure of websites using a [neo4j graph database](https://neo4j.com/) in combination with [spatie crawler](https://github.com/spatie/crawler).

The idea goes like this:

Whenever a URL is crawled, all Links will be extracted from the DOM. For all links, a node will be created and a relation `foundOn->target` is added.

```php
// UrlCrawledListener.php

public function handle($event) 
{
//...
    // Extract all links on the page
    $linksOnPage = collect((new DomCrawlerService())->extractLinksFromHtml($event->getResponse()->getBody(), $event->getUrl()));
    // For all links, create nodes and add relation
    $linksOnPage->each(fn(Link $link) => $neo4jService->link($link, $event->getUrl()));
//...
}
```

```php
// Neo4JService.php

public function link(Link $link, UriInterface $foundOnUrl): void
{
    $targetUrl = new Uri($link->getUri());

    if (!$this->doesNodeExist($targetUrl)) {
        $this->createNode($targetUrl);
    }

    if (!$this->doesNodeExist($foundOnUrl)) {
        $this->createNode($foundOnUrl);
    }

    // When this method call is disabled, the crawler is A LOT faster
    $this->createRelation($foundOnUrl, $targetUrl);
}

// ...

protected function createNode(UriInterface $uri): void
{
    // Todo: Add atttributes
    $this->runStatement(
        'USE ' . $this->getDB() . ' CREATE (n:URL {url: $url, url_hash: $hash})',
        [
            'url'  => $uri->__toString(),
            'hash' => CrawlUrl::getUrlHash($uri),
        ]
    );
}

// ...

protected function createRelation(UriInterface $from, UriInterface $to): void
{
    $this->runStatement(
        '
             USE ' . $this->getDB() . '
             MATCH (a:URL), (b:URL)
             WHERE a.url_hash = $fromURL AND b.url_hash = $toURL
             CREATE (a)-[rel:Link]->(b)
             ',
        [
            'fromURL' => CrawlUrl::getUrlHash($from),
            'toURL'   => CrawlUrl::getUrlHash($to),
        ]
    );
}
```

---

### What I tried:

I tried adding an index to the nodes to improve performance on the `MATCH` query, but that did not have a noticeable impact:

```php
$this->runStatement('USE ' . $this->getDB() . ' CREATE INDEX url_hash_index FOR (n:URL) ON (n.url_hash)');
```

I thought about creating them in a single query and not looping all found links, but I only find a documentation on how to [create multiple nodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create/#create-create-multiple-nodes-with-a-parameter-for-their-properties) - but nothing on how to create multiple relations.

I also considered storing everything in another store first and then bulk import this store into neo4j. However, the [documentation on csv imports](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_optimizing_load_csv_for_performance) uses exactly the same logic to create the relations, so that would not help neither:

```
// create relationships
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///people.csv' AS row
MATCH (e:Employee {employeeId: row.employeeId})
MATCH (c:Company {companyId: row.Company})
MERGE (e)-[:WORKS_FOR]->(c)
```

---

I already shifted the `->doesNodeExist()` logic to SQL as this caused the same problem. The `MATCH` cypher seems to be very slow overall. But I can't imagine that matching against a few hundred nodes can be that slow compared to a SQL database.

Do you have any suggestions on how to either improve the algorithm itself or the neo4j database structure or cypher query to improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace:

```php
    $targetUrl = new Uri($link->getUri());

    if (!$this->nodeExist($targetUrl)) {
        $this->createNode($targetUrl);
    }

    if (!$this->nodeExist($foundOnUrl)) {
        $this->createNode($foundOnUrl);
    }

    $this->createRelation($foundOnUrl, $targetUrl);
```

with something like:

```php
$this->runStatement('
    USE ' . $this->getDB() . '
    MERGE (a:URL {url_hash: $fromURL})
    MERGE (b:URL {url_hash: $toURL})
    CREATE (a)-[rel:Link]->(b)',
    [
        'fromURL' => CrawlUrl::getUrlHash($from),
        'toURL'   => CrawlUrl::getUrlHash($to),
    ]
);
```

Make sure you define an index (or a uniqueness constraint)  on `(:URL {url_hash})` **before** running the program.

If it is still too slow, then you'll indeed need to insert relationships by batch, with 1 query per batch (tweak the above query with `UNWIND`). You will need to experiment various batch sizes to determine what the best compromise is, in terms of import time and memory consumption (small batch => less memory => overall longer import time).

Side note: labels use `PascalCase` not `UPPER_CASE`, so `URL` should be written as `Url` (although the line is blurry when it comes to acronyms)

Comment: Thank you! unfortunately still the first 10-20 nodes are done quite fast, but then it slows down dramatically to the point where everything times out. I will try `UNWIND`.

Comment: Unwinding into the `MERGE` you gave does the job. Thank you!